# are CLR based stored procs out?

Tags: c#, sql-server

are CLR based stored procs out (from .net 4.0 +)? The last documentation i see on MSDN is for 3.5. I have used this in the past (been over a year) but none recently. I am considering going back to it to improve string manipulation performance. Any thoughts ?

Comment: @ Prix - linq to sql is the same as clr based stored proc ?

Comment: @WhatsInAName: No, AFAIU those are completely orthogonal technologies.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError i was being sarcastic :) but its good to have that comment out there so others dont mistake it.

Comment: In my typical fashion, I completely missed the irony :)